# I'm not able to pass a value to the next ViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m working on this app that runs 2 different queries to Firebase. The first Firebase query displays the data inside a pickerView, the second is a query to a “users” collection and pulls a custom field. Both queries are working as expected, pickerView displays the info and I’m able to print the results of the user’s collection to the console. The issue I’m having is that I’m trying the pass the value of the custom field to the next VC and is not working. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
       class PatfilterVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var hospNameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var getDataBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoPickerViewer: UIPickerView!

    private var textFieldSelected = UITextField()
    private var pickerView: UIPickerView?
    private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    private var userListener: ListenerRegistration!

    private var hospitalClass = [HospitalList]()
    private var hospCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
    private var hospCode: HospitalList! = nil

    private var loggedInUserClass = [UserSpecialty]()
    private var usersCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
    private var currentUserSpecialty: UserSpecialty! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        infoPickerViewer.delegate = self
        infoPickerViewer.dataSource = self

        hospNameTxt.inputView = pickerView
        hospNameTxt.delegate = self

        self.infoPickerViewer = pickerView
        self.infoPickerViewer?.delegate = self
        self.infoPickerViewer?.dataSource = self

        self.infoPickerViewer?.reloadAllComponents()

        hospCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(HOSPITAL_REF)
        usersCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(USERS_REF)

        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
             if user == nil {
                self.getDataBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                self.infoPickerViewer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
             } else {
                 self.getDataBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.infoPickerViewer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                 self.setListener()
             }
         })

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        getHospitalList()
        getUserSpecialty()

    }


    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil {

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let LoginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
                self.present(LoginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.setListener()
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if userListener != nil {
            userListener.remove()
        }
    }

    func setListener() {
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textFieldSelected = textField
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.pickerView?.reloadAllComponents()
        return true
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return hospitalClass.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return hospitalClass[row].hospitalName
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            hospCode = hospitalClass[row]
            let hosp = hospitalClass[row].hospitalName
            hospNameTxt.text = hosp
    }

    @IBAction func getDataTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard hospCode != nil else {return}
        guard currentUserSpecialty != nil else {return}

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResults", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResults" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ResultsdataVC
            if let hosp = hospCode {
                vc.hospCodeFromVC = hosp.hospitalCode
            }
            if let user = currentUserSpecialty {
                vc.userSpecFromVC = user.userSpecialtyCode
            }
        }
    }

    //this query displays in the pickerView

    func getHospitalList() {
        let hospListQuery = hospCollectionRef?
            .order(by: HOSPITAL_NAME, descending: false)

        hospListQuery?.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.infoPickerViewer.reloadAllComponents()
                let snap = snapshot
                for document in snap!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let hospitalCode = data[HOSPITAL_CODE] as? String ?? ""
                    let hospitalName = data[HOSPITAL_NAME] as? String ?? ""

                    let hospList = HospitalList(hospitalCode: hospitalCode, hospitalName: hospitalName)

                    self.hospitalClass.append(hospList)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //this query gets the values from Firebase but i cannot pass userSpecialtyCode
    // to the next viewController

    func getUserSpecialty() {
        if let loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            let docRef = usersCollectionRef.document(loggedInUser)
            docRef.getDocument { ( document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let userSpecialtyCode = data?[SPECIALTY_CODE] as? String ?? ""
                    let loggedInUserId = data?[LOGGED_IN_USER_ID] as? String ?? ""

                    let loggedUser = UserSpecialty(userSpecialtyCode: userSpecialtyCode, loggedInUserId: loggedInUserId)

                    self.loggedInUserClass.append(loggedUser)
                    print("specCode", userSpecialtyCode as Any) //IT PRINTS THE CORRECT VALUE
                    print("loggedInUser", loggedInUserId as Any) //IT PRINTS THE USER ID
                } else {
                    print("no document")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()

        } catch let signoutError as NSError {
            debugPrint("Error signing out: \(signoutError)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: @vadian I cannot pass the value inside userSpecialtyCode to the next VC. Prepare for segue gets a nil value.

Comment: Where is `getUserSpecialty()` called? This information is crucial.

Comment: it's called inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: @vadian I just updated the code with everything. Thank you

Comment: The requests to get the data work asynchronously. You could disable the `getDataTapped` button until the data is available.

Comment: The getDataTapped button is used to pass the values inside hospitalCode and userSpecialtyCode to the next VC once a value in the pickerView is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResults" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ResultsdataVC
            _ = vc.view
            if let hosp = hospCode {
                vc.hospCodeFromVC = hosp.hospitalCode
            }
            if let user = currentUserSpecialty {
                vc.userSpecFromVC = user.userSpecialtyCode
            }
        }
    }
```